# Lightbox2 Stopped Working on Chrome

Tags: lightbox2

Using straight-out-of-the-box lightbox2 (no edits, no mods). It has worked faithfully for the past couple of years since it's been in use. Suddenly noticed the other day that the image no longer fades in/out using Chrome. Image just displays on a new browser page. Works okay on Edge, but not sure about Safari as I've not yet checked that. Is this a Chrome issue? Any fixes?

Comment: Does the issue happen on the main Lightbox page? http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#examples

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Tried many things.

Then I used "lightbox with jquery" javascript that's on their website: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2

**Update**: It is not necessary to combine lightbox with jquery. The issue in my case was that I was using jquery older than version 2. If you user 2.0 or above version of Jquery, lightbox will start working again.